# Questions about parametric equations

Tags: calculus

Consider the parametric equations: $$x=t^3-3t, \; \; y=t^2+t+1.$$

1. What is the lowest point on this parametric curve?
2. For what values of $t$ does the curve move left, move right, move up and move down?
3. When is the curve concave up?
4. Find the area contained inside the loop of this curve if the curve intersects itself at the point $(-2,3)$.

Well for 1. I get $(2,1)$ after calculating $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ for $t$.
I’m not sure on 2.
For 3. we just find $t$ such that $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}>0$.
For 4. I’m not sure on this one too.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dot x=3t^2-3$$ is negative for $-1<t<1$, meaning that the curve is traversed from right to left in this range, and conversely.

$$\dot y=2t+1$$ is negative when $t\le-\dfrac12$ and the curve is traversed from top to bottom in this range and conversely. The lowest point is reached at $t=-\dfrac12$.

For the final question, use a curvilinear integral,

$$A=\oint x\,dy=\int x\dot y\,dt.$$

Comment: Great. So that means $(11/8,3/4)$ is the lowest point, not $(2,1)$.

Comment: How do you find bounds of the integral? Is it from $t=-1$ to $1$ since we solve $t^3-3t=-2$ and $t^2+t+1=3$ for $t$?

Comment: I get $-16/5$ which is negative so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I think it’s the integral of $x’y$ not $xy’$

Comment: @squenshl: it is both, with a change of sign.